# Unity3d Open editor window at the cursor position

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I've got a simple question. I would like to open an editor window in unity and have it's top left corner be at the cursor's position. I have tried setting `EditorWindow.position` to `Event.current.mousePosition` but this has yielded no results.

It seems that `Event.current.mousePosition` has it's origin at the top left of whatever window it was last in (inspector, etc.).

Any help?

Answer (score 4):

You could approach it like this (tested, works):

```
public class MyWindow : EditorWindow
{
  bool initializedPosition = false;

  ...

  void OnGUI()
  {
    if (!initializedPosition)
    {
        Vector2 mousePos = GUIUtility.GUIToScreenPoint(Event.current.mousePosition);
        position = new Rect(mousePos.x, mousePos.y, position.width, position.height);
        initializedPosition = true;
    }

    ...
}
```